# How to deal with temporary data in mysql/mariadb?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

### Scenario

Let's say we need to store data in our database that is only relevant for a limited amount of time (e.g. user tokens). And after that time the data is completely irrelevant.

To make it a little bit more specific:

- The data itself is quite limited (couple of timestamps, short strings)
- The time is ~30 days
- There would be an index on another column than the primary key
- Every day there would be a couple of thousand new rows added
- InnoDB is the storage engine

### Questions

- What would be the preferred way to handle this scenario?
- Would it be ok to just delete old rows? Would this reclaim disk space?
- What about the index? Would the index need regular maintenance?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For extremely short duration data, I'd prefer to use a cache server like Redis or Memcached. Those are truly volatile storage, being in dynamic RAM only (though Redis has an option to store persistently, it is not used by default). They are very fast, they have options for automatically expiring data, and they are efficient about recovering memory after you delete data. The downside is if the server restarts, all the data in RAM is lost.

But you mentioned your tokens need to be stored for up to 30 days. I think it would be safer to use persistent storage for these. Many apps do use a database, but you could also use simple files on a filesystem. Or Redis with the persistent option enabled.

If you use MySQL in the InnoDB storage engine, you can delete rows. InnoDB tablespaces do not shrink, but they do reuse empty extends sometimes (though this is a bit unpredictable). Over time, an InnoDB tablespace that has a lot of turnover tends to get fragmented, and it takes a lot more storage for the same number of rows. Eventually you may find it beneficial to use OPTIMIZE TABLE, which will copy the data to a new tablespace in a more compact manner, and drop the original tablespace. I'd do this no more than once a month.

Unfortunately, there's no way to check a tablespace to see if it's in need of optimizing. You just have to try it and see if it shrinks significantly.

The steps of OPTIMIZE TABLE effectively rebuilds all the indexes of a table. That's all that is needed for index "maintenance."

Comment: I guess sometimes you need to think outside the box. Using redis with a persistent storage here is probably smarter than making it work in mysql. Thanks for that input!

Answer (score 0):

No problem for InnoDB.

Case 1:  The app takes a month to add 60K rows, then suddenly removes all of the rows and starts over:

Use `TRUNCATE TABLE` for the removal.

Case 2:  Each row is working on its own time scale.  For example, the rows added on Jan 12 are deleted on Feb 12:

Simply `DELETE` the rows when they expire.  Don't worry about fragmentation, holes, indexes, etc; InnoDB will be efficient enough.  Anyway, 60K rows is "small".  Do be sure to have an index that is designed to help find the rows to delete when it is time.

That is a mere 1 or 2 rows being added each minute and deleted each minute.  Even if it were "each second", I would give the same answer.  If it were "each millisecond", I might suggest something else.

In neither case would I bother with `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.